# Is there any event can tell me that IE has finished its contenteditable action?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, contenteditable

I am working on an text editor based on `contenteditable`  trying to modify IE's contenteditable behaviour.

eg: insert `<br />` not a new `<p>` element when press enter

I found IE finishes its contenteditable behaviour between `keyup` and `keydown` while typing. So I could add my modification when these two events fired.

But when coming to `Paste` , it doesn't work.

case is:
     I want paste a text block of several paragraphs like this

```
paragraph 1

another paragraph

and so on
```

IE will automatically embed paragraph in a new `<p>` tag. If I want to for example add `class` to these `<p>` elements, I need to know when these elements have been created.

I've try `onpaste`, `nodeInserted`. They all fired before change happened. Is there any event fired after IE has finished its job??

Comment: Not exactly related to the question, but check [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9nLWy/1/). It contains a snippet I've created for IE8, and I can't remember there was any troubles when pasting text. It seems to work also in IE10.

Answer (score 0):

I've been detecting it using keypress event.
If I remember corectly, you can get pressed keys and modifiers from input param, to detect Ctrl+v.

**EDIT**
Obviously not, I just checked. JQuery does id using 'paste' event.

HTML

```
<p id="cont" contenteditable="true">This is an editable paragraph.</p>
```

Javascript

```
$("#cont").keypress(function() {
    console.log("Keypress " + Math.random());
});

$("#cont").bind('paste', function(e){
    console.log("Paste " + Math.random());
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3djRp/3/

**EDIT2**
I borrowed [someone elses event combination](http://jsfiddle.net/3djRp/5/) do detect paste after content change, but in some browsers it fires twice.

```
$cont = $("#cont");

$cont.data('oldval', $cont.text());
//console.log($cont.data('oldval'));

$cont.bind("propertychange input keyup paste", function(event){
    if($cont.data('oldval') != $cont.text()) {
        //console.log("old " + $cont.data('oldval'));
        //console.log("new " + $cont.text());
        $cont.data('oldVal', $cont.text());

        console.log('change: ' + $cont.text());
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but these events are fired before IE finish its work on contenteditable element.

Comment: as I test in IE10, [paste fires before change happens](http://jsfiddle.net/iq72/Y2Ch6/12/)  But for this specific problem I found an smart way , detecting elements inserted by detect animantion at [David Walsh's Blog](http://davidwalsh.name/detect-node-insertion)